# Is it possible to redefine columns (and things defined in settings) in js datatable via ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am aware that thanks to `fnReloadAjax` or combination of `fnClearTable()` and `fnAddData()` I can reload some fresh data

but is it possible this way somehow to redefine settings of table, in particulary: columns names, which are hidden, which are visible?

**UPDATE**: 
If you will decide for destroying the table the easier way as checking existence and destroying like this:

```
if $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#element") {
    $('#element').DataTable().destroy();
}
```

can be **just setting the property in DataTable definition**: `bDestroy: true`

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to change column names via datatables methods, no. But seems like it is possible using JQuery directly against the table: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/924/change-column-name-on-the-fly

Comment: If you are talking about showing/hiding columns - have a look at this: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html - you can use the `.visible` toggle method in the success callback of an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can redfine the settings by destroying the dataTable altogether like:

```
//part1
    $( "#element" ).dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
          { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }         //cannot sort using column 1
         ]
        });



----------
//part2

    $( "#element" ).dataTable().fnDestroy();

    $('#element').dataTable( {
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [2] }     //hiding the column 3
            ]
        } );
```

Here I just destroyed the dataTable for no reason but you can link it with some event.

Comment: That is a way I can think of!! Haven't seen any other answer, did we? I would be very much eager to see any other way of doing..

Comment: btw I think `$( "#element" ).dataTable().fnDestroy();` won't work, and you need: `if $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#element") {$('#element').DataTable().destroy();}`

Comment: which version of datatable ar you runing? I was trying to replace your destroy and it stop working. My coffe code: https://gist.github.com/andilab/d07d7a0150d0281683c2

Comment: I am using version `1.10.2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60608/discussion-between-sri-and-andi).